# Django CheckboxSelectMultiple allow none

Tags: django

I need some help, I'm using a `forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField` to represent a `ManyToManyField`, rendered as a `widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple`.

All work perfect but the problem come when none checkbox was selected, it raises a validationError when ask `form.is_valid()`.

I need Select None, One, Many or All.
It is any way to allow blank or empty?
Thanks!!

Comment: can you show some code. what have you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validation_error will be raised if the `model` requires a value to be filed in the field,

So simply set your model field with `null= True`, and `blank = True`

choices_field=models.CharField(`null = True, blank = True)`

and in the forms.py you can set it to `required = False`